# Hibernate Cannot find Query Parameter even though it's there

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple hibernate query:

```
    public AtMessage getMessageById(int messageId)
    {
        AtMessage message = (AtMessage) session.createQuery(
         "FROM com.persistence.AtMessage where atMessageKey=:atMessageKey"
        ).setParameter("atMessageKey", messageId).uniqueResult();
        return message;
    }
```

when I call the method, I get a `org.hibernate.QueryParameterException` with the message `could not locate named parameter [atMessageKey]`

I don't get why this is happening as the query looks right.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.  I was using the shade plugin in Maven to package all the jars into an Uber JAR.

Not using the shade plugin and just adding all the JARs on the classpath made the problem go away.

Not sure what the exact reason is why Hibernate fails in this peculiar way, but I have a workaround now.  To be clear, it's not failing to find the config file - if I put the wrong DB user/pass in it will fail with a connection error.  So it IS finding the config, class mapping just seems to be wonky.